# Azure Function, Autofac, Serilog

Tags: c#, azure-functions, autofac, serilog

What I want to use:

- Azure Function (isolated) V4 with .NET6.
- AutoFac as DI engine.
- Serilog as Logging engine.

The code is (simplified version, no try/catch, and other):

```
    Log.Logger = LoggerConfigurationFactory
        .GetLoggerConfiguration(LogEventLevel.Debug)
        .CreateLogger();
    IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = GetConfiguration();
    
    IHost host = new HostBuilder()
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.Remove(
                services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)));
            services.Remove(
                services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<>)));
    
            services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(_ => new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true));
            services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog(Log.Logger));
    
            Autofac.ContainerBuilder containerBuilder = new();
    
            containerBuilder.Populate(services);
            ConfigureContainer(containerBuilder, configurationRoot);
        })
        .Build();
    
    await host
        .RunAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But the output on the console is (sorry for the bulleted list):

- [2023-01-18T16:15:38.238Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 9984) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
- [2023-01-18T16:15:42.934Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A74958CE'.
- [2023-01-18T16:15:44.781Z] [2023-01-18T17:15:44.6592148 +01:00|DBG] [] [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.MoveNext()] Hosting starting
- [2023-01-18T16:15:44.786Z] [2023-01-18T17:15:44.7769259 +01:00|DBG] [] [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.MoveNext()] Hosting starting
- [2023-01-18T16:15:46.919Z] [2023-01-18T17:15:46.9065003 +01:00|INF] [] [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ConsoleLifetime.OnApplicationStarted()] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
- [2023-01-18T16:15:46.926Z] [2023-01-18T17:15:46.9184378 +01:00|INF] [] [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ConsoleLifetime.OnApplicationStarted()] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

As you can see, there are two problems:

1. Starting from the third line, the DateTime is duplicated (while my template has only one).
2. The Log entries are duplicated.

How can I solve the problem?